# Smart UV project to seams

Tags: uv

How I can bake islands created by Smart UV project to seams?

I have mesh which is hard to unwrap manually, but Smart UVs do the job well. I need to joint this mesh with mesh with manually selected seams and unwrap again. So I need to bake seams created by Smart UVs to mesh, so they will work with the manually selected seams.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/seams.html#mark-seams-from-island

Comment: @FFeller OMG how could I not have noticed. Thanks